# Angular route params in GitHub pages

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5, github-pages

Can I get route parameters in my Angular 5 application if it is hosted at GitHub pages?

**https://khex.github.io/myapp/1234**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home/:id', component: AppComponent }
];
```

After loading app make redirect to root domain `khex.github.io` and throw an error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run any angular app the router will match whatever host its on. If your app is hosted on github pages then by definition you'll be able to access the route params.

Comment: maybe I need some special dance with rote config becase it make redirect.

Comment: Put home before redirect